# how to select each element from a string after implode

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array, and I imploded it into a string. Now how can i select each element from that string?

```
$shop['cat2'] = $cat2;
$allstring= implode(",", $cat2)
foreach ($allstring as $each_string_value){
}
```

This is not working as I am getting an error "invalid argument supplied foreach()

Comment: foreach ($cat2 as $each_string_value) ... should work.

Comment: You have missing semicolon before foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Just use the initial array inside the `foreach` loop:

```
$shop['cat2'] = $cat2;
$allstring = implode(",", $cat2);

foreach ($cat2 as $each_string_value)
{
    // Do your loop stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` expects an array, but you are passing in a string. Why do you implode the variable `$cat2` at all, if you need it as an array? Just use your `foreach`, but pass `$cat2` directly:

```
foreach( $cat2 as $each_string_value )
{
    /* … */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't extract data from a string using for each you you want extract data using `foreach` after `implode` please using following code :

```
$shop['cat2'] = $cat2;
$allstring= implode(",", $cat2);
$newaray=expolde(',', $allstring);

foreach($newaray as $values) {
    echo $values;
}
```